# Replace an array items in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like below. In propertymixed array I have an array I want to replace array with ch_array items.

```
var myObject = {
    propertyString: "this is a string",
    propertyAnotherString: "this is another string",
    propertyMixedArray: [{"item 1"},{ "item 2"}, {"item 3"}],  
    propertyObject: { someProperty: "and so on..." }
};

ch_array =[{"new val1"},{ "new val 2"}, {"newval3"}];

var myObject = {
    propertyString: "this is a string",
    propertyAnotherString: "this is another string",
    propertyMixedArray: [{"new val1"},{ "new val 2"}, {"newval3"}],  
    propertyObject: { someProperty: "and so on..." }
};
```

Comment: `myObject.propertyMixedArray = ch_array`?

Comment: simple... `myObject.propertyMixedArray = ch_array;`

Comment: These are not proper JS assignments

Comment: @nnnnnn `ch_array =[{"new val1"},{ "new val 2"}, {"new val 3"}];` really..?

Comment: @Redu - Yes, I realised that immediately after commenting, which is why I immediately deleted that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the property to the new array:

```
myObject.propertyMixedArray = ch_array;
```